# HD camera through hdmi for Skype

Tags: video, hdmi, cable, camera, video-streaming

I have a Panasonic hd-sd90 camera and hdmi mini to big cable. How can I configure video source from hdmi for skype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are plugging the HDMI into your computer's video card then you are not connecting it correctly. You will want to use either IEEE1394 (Firewire) or USB. You may need to download the drivers for the Panasonic camera on the computer.

The HDMI that you're plugging it into is an output device. You basically have a cable connecting to two different output devices and that's why nothing is working.